# Can there be one "Co-Founder"?

Tags: meaning, differences

Assuming there is a company that was founded by two people (A and B), one of them is also the CEO (A).

- Is it correct to say that A is the *founder* and B is the (only) *co-founder*? Or does *co-founder* always imply that there has to be more than one *co-founder*, e.g. A and B are both *co-founders* (or *founders*) of that company?
- Can the term *co-founder* ever imply being a subordinate to the *founder*?

Comment: You could actually broaden this question to be about the prefix "co-" in general.  Can an article have one author and one co-author?  Can a dwelling have one inhabitant and one co-habitant?  Can a charity event have one sponsor and one co-sponsor?  And so on.  Note that a commercial airplane clearly *does* have a pilot and a copilot.

Comment: *Co-* generally implies an equal and symmetric relationship (though my instinct tingles when I think of a "co-pilot" or "co-author" having equal authority; I know it's true, but it doesn't *feel* true).

Comment: I think any organization where one person self-identifies as "the" ***founder***, but one or more others consider themselves to be ***co-founders*** would quickly collapse in acrimony and disarray.

Comment: I don't think so - just as an individual who doesn't *have* a partner can't be said to *be* a partner.

Comment: @cobaltduck: an article can certainly have one ***principal author*** and a lot of co-authors. And in fact, if you Google, you find ***co-principal author***, so presumably an article can have several ***co-principal authors*** and lots of co-authors. But I suspect *principal principal author* and *co-principal principal author* are used only in satires, if at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two relevant meanings of the prefix ***co-*** in *Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary* (2003):

> **3 a :** one that is associated in an action with another : fellow : partner {*co*author} {*co*worker} **b :** having a usu. lesser share in duty or responsibility : alternate : deputy {*co*pilot}

It should be evident from the examples given that, in the 3(a) sense of *co-*, there is no necessary equality of importance, prestige, or effort between the persons yoked as co-whatevers: One person may have been responsible for 90 percent of a coauthored book; one person may paid ten times as much as a coworker and be worth that much more to the company they both work for.

But the possibility that co-titled individuals may be very unequal in participation or status creates a murky boundary between *co-* in Merriam-Webster's sense 3(a) and *co-* in its sense 3(b). And I can readily imagine that some companies might choose to designate one person as "principal founder" (or simply "founder") and another person as "cofounder" in the 3(b) sense of "having a lesser share in duty or responsibility" for the company's founding.

From the outside, with nothing more to go on than the bare job titles, we have no way of gauging whether a "founder" and a "cofounder" are in fact coequal cofounders (in the 3(a) sense of *co-*) or are senior and junior or primary and secondary participants—a founder and a cofounder, in the "pilot and copilot" sense suggested by the 3(b) sense of *co-*. But if one company chooses to identify two people of unequal founding status as titularly equal "cofounders," while another company facing exactly the same situation chooses to identify one as "founder" and the other as "cofounder," I don't think that we have any clear basis for asserting that either decision constitutes a misuse of the word *cofounder* and, therefore, is objectively wrong.

Answer (score 1):

A *co-founder* can never be the subordinate of the *founder*.  They are of equal stature and are peers.

The sentence  *"A is the founder and B is the [only] co-founder"* is not wrong, but try using *"A and B are co-founders"* or *"both A and B are founders of the company"*.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Cobaltduck and Sven Yargs mentioned "co-pilot"; how would you explain that word? I think it's a good example of a situation where "[noun]" and "co-[noun]" are not equal.

Comment: @sumellic - "Co-pilot" seems to be an exception. It is opposed to "Captain". But both  pilots, the captain and the co-pilot equally shares the aircraft control: the 2 sides of the cockpit include the same commands and equipment.